# Who wants hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

**UPDATE:** Since there is a net positive upvote and no opposition, I will notify the Stack Exchange staff that we will **opt in** for the Winter Bash.

---

It's that time of year again. It's time for the Winter Bash of 2013!

You may remember this from [last year](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394/do-you-want-hats) when our site participated in this event. For those who don't know, the Winter Bash is an annual event that Stack Exchange sites have the option to participate.

Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users can earn "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (similar to the idea of badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat which can then be placed on their gravatar.

An example from past years:

[image: hats]

This event will run from December 16, through January 3, 2014. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/, which will contain a landing page and explanation of the event.

If you individually do not want to participate, you can turn off all hats via an "I hate hats" option. Once the event is over, all hats will go back into storage. The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

If you feel like this is a good or bad idea for the site, please voice your opinion. We collectively will need to choose to **opt-in** or **opt-out** by providing an response to the Stack Exchange staff. A response for the site is due by **December 1, 2013**.

The moderators will handle the communication to the Stack Exchange staff regarding the participation decision. This event is completely optional and there is no obligation to participate. No response automatically means that we will opt-out of the event.

Answer (score 0):

Bring on the hats!!

[image]